# Литература по разработке приложений на мобильные устройства

Tags: android, windows

Хочу научится разрабатывать приложения на моб.устройства желательно на Windows 8 и Android.
Я уже знаю HTML/CSS/JavaScript имею опыт в веб-разработке, хотел бы разрабатывать через эти языки. Порекомендуйте пожалуйста литературу, сайты и т.п

Answer (score 0, accepted):

знания только HTML/CSS/JavaScript явно недостаточно. Серверную часть вы на чем писать будете? На JavaScript? Серверный JS, насколько я знаю, это пока что только Node.js, но на нем приложения под мобильные устройства не пишутся (могу, конечно, ошибаться, поправьте, если не прав). Если вдруг есть желание писать под Android, то придется учить Java (впрочем, оно и к лучшему - программист, знающий только то, что вы указали в большинстве случаев полноценным программистом вряд может считаться). Если же вы вдруг (по неопытности, например) думаете, что раз знакомы с JavaScript, то и с Java быстро разберетесь, то спешу вас разочаровать - кроме схожести названий и (частично) синтаксиса общего у этих языков мало. Кроме того, под Android можно писать и на C# ([пруф](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid), тут же и документацию можно найти). Знание c# вам также поможет, если захотите разрабатывать под WinPhpne (или как он там нынче зовется)

Что касается книг, то [вот](http://it-ebooks.info/book/644/), [вот](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Android-Application-Development-Guides/dp/1118102274) и еще [вот](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1430239301). Это что касается Android. А  [вот](http://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/162305/) по Windows 8, причем специально для вас - JavaScript и все такое

Comment: а на русском есть что-то?

Comment: может и есть, но вряд ли что-то очень хорошее. Книг вроде "Программирование под Android за 2 дня и 100500 денег", думаю, если не навалом, то более, чем достаточно..только вот нужны ли вам такие книжки?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) или [Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/developers/).

Comment: PhoneGap не стоит рассматривать, лагающая недоделка, лучше писать на Java/C#.